# Failed to convert true into a drawable

Tags: android, android-studio

I have imported the [Circle Layout library](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout) on Android Studio. When I try to insert this code in activity_main.xml:

```
<ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:angleOffset="90.0">

    <!-- Add here any views you want -->

</ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout>
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to convert true into a drawable java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value 'true' must start with #   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:73)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:264)   at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:674)   at ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout.<init>(CircleLayout.java:93)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
```

What can I do in order to solve this problem? Also, which other pieces of my code could I post here to help solve the problem?

Full activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">



<ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:angleOffset="90.0">

    <!-- Add here any views you want -->
    <View android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="ok"/>

</ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you try adding a `<View ... />` in between the `CircleLayout` tags?

Comment: Nothing happens, the problem persists.

Comment: Would we be able to have you provide more code? For example: your full `activity_main.xml` and related "main activity" Java code?

Comment: I've added activity_main.xml . MainActivity.java's code is still the default code, nothing added yet.

Comment: Thanks for adding that; does this error still happen if you add something like `android:background="#ff0000"` to your `<View />` section in the XML?

Comment: Yes, it's still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
app:angleOffset="90.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me Android Studio placed the drawable in the wrong directory. Make sure it is in the right resources directory.